# Detecting the annotations of an Action inside of a servlet filter

Tags: java, annotations, servlet-filters, struts-1

I would like to use a servlet filter of type `javax.servlet.Filter` to check if the calling Action class contains a particular annotation. So something like

```
@CustomAnnotation
public class MyAction extends Action {
    // action stuff
}



public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // somehow check if the calling Action contains @CustomAnnotation
}
```

Is this possible to do inside of my Filter? If not, how could I go about filtering based on annotation?

Comment: Did you try isAnnotationPresent() of class Class?

Comment: @Joe.b the issue is that I don't have a hold of the Action class to call that method.

Comment: You're asking basically the same question over and over. S1 doesn't work like S2. The action servlet isn't hit until the "before" filters run.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know, I was just desperate and trying to refine my question. I should have just made changes to the original one. Thank you for the info though.